# Where is 'NODE_ENV' being set to 'production'?

Tags: node.js, npm

I just tried to run `npm install` to install some packages newly added as dev dependencies to `package.json`. To my surprise I couldn't get npm to install any of the new dev dependencies. After digging around I realised that the NODE_ENV environmental variable is set to `production`. This appears to be set as default when I open a new shell (I can see this using `printenv`), and it isn't being done in my `~/.bash_profile`. Inside `~/.npmrc` only contains commented lines, so **where might it be being set?**

EDIT:

I'm on OSX, and there is nothing wrong with the `package.json`. I can install dev dependencies using `NODE_ENV=development npm install`.

It's not being set in:

```
~/.bashrc
~/.bash_profile
~/.npmrc
/etc/profile.d/*
```

Comment: Depending on your OS it could be in /etc/environment or /etc/profile.d/<some file>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of places to check:

```
~/.bashrc
~/.bash_profile
~/.npmrc
~/.zshrc (if you've got zsh installed)
/etc/profile.d/env (or similar file)
```

You could always run `export NODE_ENV=development` immediately before running `npm install`, or see here for more information about npm install:

https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#production

Might want to paste your package.json file here and have someone sanity check your devDependencies declaration.

EDIT: You should also be able to force it with `npm install --dev`

Comment: Thanks. `npm install --dev` suffers from a recursion issue. Using `NODE_ENV=development npm install` works. Nothing being set in `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`,  `~/.npmrc`, or anything in `/etc/profile.d`.

Comment: it's also possible that you're using some app on your system that bases itself on Node, or maybe a test webserver running somewhere, that's setting `NODE_ENV` in it's startup script.  Either way, it'd be worth adding a line to your .bash_profile anyway, then at least you're covered on a per session shell basis.

Comment: I've looked high and low and I have no idea what is setting it. I am now setting `NODE_ENV` to `development` in my `~/.bash_profile`.